# Matlab - interp2-like function for use with 2D arrays?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I have a 2D array of latitude values (99x3392) (called 'y3') and a 2D array of longitude values (99x3392) (called 'x3').  I also have a third separate 2D array of a variable's values that corresponds to these lat/lon points (99x3392) (called 'SLA').  Lastly, I have a mxn array (2x5000) that has a different set of lat/lon points from a ship track (called 'trackline').  What I would like to do is find the lat/lon values in x3 and y3 that correspond with the values in 'trackline', so I can ultimately pull out the variable values in 'SLA', however, I am not sure how to do with with x3 and y3 being two different 2D arrays.  I tried to convert them all to 1D arrays and use interp2, but this did not work properly.  Can anyone give me a hand in figuring this out please?  Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: To find the lat/on in X3 and y3: You first need to traverse x3 2d array and then traverse the y3 2d array, once you get the first values on both x3 and y3 2d arrays then you check if they correspond.

Comment: `interp2` take 2D arrays as input, just feed your arrays as they are to `interp2` and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TriScatteredInterp for this purpose.

http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html